# Make a table of means and frequency in r

Tags: r

I want to make a table of means and frequency in RStudio resembling this one:

[Table by country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkFeS.jpg)

I have the exact same data as the authors of the article, but i cannot figure out how to do a resembling table in R without using excel.

Thanks!

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide the data and a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451) of what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package to do this

depending on the data the code can be something like

```
mydata %>%    
group_by(Gender, Country) %>%    
summarise(Age = mean(age),  Weight = mean(weight), n = n() [...])
```

There is a good tutorial for that:
http://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial

Comment: But i want the rows to be variables so the columns are divided in country, and when i run your code i get an errormessage that the variables isn't found...

Comment: Shouldn't be a big deal. How does the data looks like, can you add the first few lines?

Comment: @Codutie you wrote `plyr` but you meant `dplyr`.